# How do I get a bot to not only consider itself

Tags: python, discord.py

This code should return the number of members and their status of whether they are online or offline. However, it only produced one member as being online and everyone else offline which is not true. When I tested to see which members it was considering (print(member)) it turns out the bot was only considering itself. Any help in telling me how to get the bot to consider the members of the server and not itself would be appreciated.

```
@client.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    count=0 
    for member in ctx.guild.members: 
        if member.status is not discord.Status.offline:
            count += 1 
            print(member)
    
    all_users = ctx.guild.member_count
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'**{ctx.guild.name}** Stats', color=0x000)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=all_users)
    embed.add_field(name="Online", value=f'{count} :green_circle:', inline=True) 
    embed.add_field(name="Offline", value =f'{all_users - count} :red_circle:', inline = True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Do you have member intents enabled?

Comment: No and I dont know what that is

Comment: Then that is probably your issue. Read up on intents here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use `member.bot` to check if they are a bot, as you may way to exclude them from your logic all together, if you are doing a member count.

You could also just `-1` from your member count too.

If you really want to exclude just the bot itself, you can use `client.user` to get your user ID and `member.user` to get the current member, and compare them.